# VSCode autocompletion for C# on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup an environment to code a Unity projet on my Ubuntu 20.04 computer.

I want to use VSCode to write my C# code. As required, I installed .NET SDK 5.0.201.

So, I tried to run some code but VSCode does not seem to recognize my .NET installation. Every time I open VSCode, I get the following message :

```
The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.
```

And (the main problem), I do not have auto-completion on my C# code.

I don't really understand what is the problem here. .NET is correctly recognized in my terminal (both ubuntu terminal and terminal inside VSCode)

```
>> dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.201
 Commit:    a09bd5c86c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /snap/dotnet-sdk/116/sdk/5.0.201/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.4
  Commit:  f27d337295

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.201 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/116/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/116/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/116/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

What am I missing here ?

EDIT

The C# extension can't load either and give me the following message :

```
The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/path/to/my/project/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/path/to/my/project/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/home/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.9/.omnisharp/1.37.6/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1180,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

Comment: For autocompletion, install additional extension like Roslynator.

Comment: Well, I did installed some extensions, but it seems that they don't load because of the problem I have

Comment: Did you install [C# for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)?

Comment: Yes this is the extension I installed. I edited the post with the log message this extension gives me when I start VSCode

Comment: I'm not affiliated with jetbrains but I highly recommend Rider on Linux. It's 1000 times better than omnisharp + vscode. It's even better than visual studio on windows sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer !

In VSCode setting, I configured

```
"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"
```

Instead of

```
"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "auto"
```

And it did the trick